# How can I say "I feel ya"?

Tags: translation

People often use "I feel ya", when texting in English. What can I say in Esperanto?

I guess "Mi komprenas" or "Mi kompatas vin" are options. Is there something more "laidback"?

Comment: Does the fact you are using _ya_ mean you are asking for an informal/slang way of saying that?

Comment: Yes, the slang-part is intended.

Answer (score 11):

I would text ***Kunsente***. I tend to use adverbs for single-word sentences. In the list I have included the *-at-, -it-*, but they feel a bit fussy to me. Other people should have a wider range of suggestions.

- *Prave* — Truly
- *Certe* — Certainly
- *Konsent(it)e* — Agreed
- *Kunsent(at)e* — I feel ya
- *Kompren(it)e* — Understood
- *Kompaton/Kompate* — Sorry to hear that
- *Ĉiam tiel* — Always the way

Answer (score 4):

To my friends I have sometimes said "mi sentas same" = I feel the same. "mi komprenas" is probably something else I have said or would say (probably if I don't actually feel the same, but I get where they're coming from).

Answer (score 3):

I use "same mi" a lot, but I don't think I use it in the sense "I feel ya" is meant. But if one wants to say "mi sentas same", an abbreviation of that is better in tis context.
I use it to say "I feel the same", but I think it's broadly applicable.