# Short and concise way of saying "Don't we all."

Tags: translation

I was chatting in the ecology group today and someone wrote "Mi ege devas sportumi pli." In English I'd respond with "Don't we all.", as a way of saying "jes, mi bone komprenas vin. Kiel ni cxiuj.".

I wasn't really satisfied with any of my translations of it, as they all seemed to need so many words. It wasn't really "punchy".

I guess this is very similar to [How can I say "I feel ya"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/how-can-i-say-i-feel-ya) , and it is also slang or informal language, but I am looking for something that gives the feeling that we all share this feeling, not just me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

"Don't we all" can be used in a few different situations, and I would render these differently in Esperanto.

"Yes, that's obvious"

- I think Esperanto is wonderful // Yes, **don't we all!**
- *Mi kredas ke Esperanto estas bonega // jes **klare!***

"Me too, but it will never happen."

- I wish I could find a cute guy who doesn't misuse the accusative // **Don't we all!**
- *Mi sopiras trovi belan viron kiu ne pekas kontraŭ la akuzativo // **Bela revo!***

Answer (score 5):

I think *Kiel ni ĉiuj!* is good, actually, but here are some more ideas:

- *La samo ĉie!* or *Kaj ĉie la samo!* or *Por ĉiu la samo!* or *Samas por ĉiu!* or just *Same!*
- *Tio pravas ĉiuflanke!* or *ambaŭflanke!*
- *Ĉiuflanke!* or *Ambaŭflanke!*
- *Kiel ankaŭ la mondo!*
- *Vi ne estas unu tiurilate!* or *Vi ne solsolas, ulo!*
- *Universale!*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could say *bona diro* or *kompreneble*

Comment: Could you explain "bondiro" in more detail? I would say that's not a real word.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Bondiro = A good saying

Comment: How is that different from "bona diro"?

Comment: Compound nouns are created from prepositional phrases. So there is not much difference between "bona diro" and "bondiro". http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq040.html#sec4-1-2

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you have misunderstood Jordan's explanation here. There is not a single example in section 4.1.2. on Compound Nouns where an adjective root is is included. He even says explicitly that the meaning of such compounds are often different then when expressed with an adjective and noun. Following the pattern ***bondiro*** would be ***diro de bono*** - saying of goodness or saying of the good - and certainly not *bona diro*.