# How can I say "relate (to someone)" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

In regular conversations, a certain use of the verb "relate" is quite common. My impression is that it means one recognizes or is able to understand a situation someone else is experiencing. For example:

- After my father died, I lost all interest in my work.   — I can relate to that, the same thing happened to me when my mother passed away.
- My first Esperanto-meetup was amazing. It was as if, until then, I had not fully believed the language works. — I can totally relate!
- I have trouble realting to the main character. Maybe that is the reason I didn't enjoy the book.

What can I say in Esperanto?

Comment: What is the difference to the similar question http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/how-can-i-say-i-feel-ya you asked last Octobre? Were you not content with the answers?

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use:

- *Same/Simile okazis al mi* for "I can relate to that".
- *identiĝi al* or *kunsenti kun* for "to relate to something"

So for your examples :

> After my father died, I lost all interest in my work. — I can relate to that
>
> Post kiam mia patro mortis, mi tute malinteresiĝis pri mia laboro. — *Same okazis al mi*
>
> I have trouble relating to the main charachter.
>
> Estas malfacile por mi *kunsenti kun* la ĉefa rolulo.

Answer (score 1):

For ”I can relate to that” I’d say ”(Ho,) mi konas tion”. (I thought your question about ”I feel ya” had already been answered, as Cyril points out?)

Comment: You're right. When I went to sleep some memory of that I had already asked about "I feel ya" came up in my mind. I edited the question now to make it different. It was actually almost a copy of the other question earlier! haha, my bad

Comment: haha, that’s what happens sometimes. :-)